# Как найти все файлы больше 100kb?

Tags: python, python-2.x

Параметр расширенных файлов:

```
files_lazy_lister = your_wrapper (os.walk ("c:\\"), min_size_kb = 100)
list(files_lazy_lister)
```

пример вывода =>

```
"C: \\ Windows \\ bfsvc.exe", 3588L
"C: \\ Windows \\ explorer.exe", 1583L
"C: \\ Windows \\ explorer.exe", 101
"C: \\ Windows \\ explorer.exe", 100
```

---

```
import os
import pprint

def generator_files(absolute_address, min_size_kb):
    for address, dirs, files in absolute_address:
        for file in files:
            size = os.path.getsize(os.path.join(address, file)) >> 10 >= min_size_kb
            absolute_path = os.path.join(address, file), size
            yield absolute_path

    return

all_files = generator_files(os.walk('С:\\'), min_size_kb=100)
pprint.pprint(list(all_files))
```

Как вывести фалы больше 100kb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Также можно воспользоваться удобным модулем [pathlib для Python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) или [pathlib2 для Python 2.x](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib2/):

```
try:
    from pathlib import Path       # Python 3.x
except ImportError:
    from pathlib2 import Path      # Python 2.x  (pip install pathlib2)

def get_file_size(path, min_sz_bytes=0):
    return [(str(f.absolute()), f.stat().st_size)
            for f in Path(path).glob('**') 
            if f.stat().st_size >= min_sz_bytes]
```

Comment: Работаем только на Python 2.x
Спасибо! Почитаю.

Comment: @iamsuperoleg, это решение будет работать и для Python 3.x и для Python 2.x (надо установить `pathlib2`)

Comment: Да, я понял. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

Принимает на вход путь и размер в килобайтах, а возвращает список, содержащий кортежи с путем к файлу и его размером

```
import os
def get_size(path, size=None):
    res = []
    for path, folders, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            full_path = os.path.join(path,file)
            file_size = os.path.getsize(full_path) >> 10
            if file_size >= size:
                res.append((full_path, file_size))
            elif size is None
                res.append((full_path, file_size))
    return(res)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Не мог понять куда условие запихнуть.

Comment: Никуда  вызов вернет список  в котором будут содержаться только файлы большее указанного размера get_size('c:/', 100)

Comment: Под условием я имел ввиду:           
`if file_size > size * 1e+3:
      res.append((full_path, size))`
пихал перед for и про локальный не подумал.

Comment: в строке`res.append((full_path, size))` должно быть `res.append((full_path, file_size))`

Comment: опечатка получилась :3

Comment: Если искать файлы на диске C: `all_files = generator_files(os.walk('C:\\Users\\'))` то с некоторыми папками выбивает ошибку:
`WindowsError: [Error 2] : 'C:\\Users\\Balcevich\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Themes\\Community\\DesktopBackground\\17_sasapetrovic-chotteldjeridtunisia.jpg'` с диском D: все работает.

Comment: Ошибка в том что выводит все файлы в названии которых латиница, не подскажите как вывести файлы с любым названием? (на Python 2.x)

Comment: Взять и погуглить, а не ожидать, что все сделают за тебя. В python2 есть несколько разновидностей строк: байтовые и юникодные. Полагаю проблема в этом. Подробнее тут https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_Python_2.6#%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8_Unicode

Comment: да уже пол дня гуглю, 100500 способов перепробовал :(

Comment: Про "Строки unicode" я читал, да это избавляет от ошибки, но не выводит русский, арабский ... текст (Python 2.x). Спасибо за ссылку.

Comment: еще можно в начале файла просто сделать импорт  `from __future__ import unicode_literals`